# Set color of copied primitive uv spheres

Tags: blender

I am creating multiple copies of a sphere, but I want to change the color of each individual sphere. Here is the code I use to create the initial sphere and then make copies of it.

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=radius)
sphere = bpy.context.object

def makeSphere(x,y,z,r,g,b):
    ob = sphere.copy()
    ob.location.x = x
    ob.location.y = y
    ob.location.z = z

    # Attempt to change sphere's color
    activeObject = bpy.context.active_object 
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="MaterialName")
    activeObject.data.materials.append(mat) 
    bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (r/255,g/255,b/255) 

    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob)
```

The script compiles and runs fine, but the colors of the spheres do not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things, `bpy.context.object` and `bpy.context.active_object` are the same object. You are duplicating the object, but not the object data that has the materials, this means you are appending each new material to the same object data but the first material is the only one being used.

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=.3)
sphere = bpy.context.object

def makeSphere(x,y,z,r,g,b):
    ob = sphere.copy()
    ob.data = sphere.data.copy()
    ob.location.x = x
    ob.location.y = y
    ob.location.z = z

    # Attempt to change sphere's color
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="MaterialName")
    mat.diffuse_color = (r/255,g/255,b/255)
    ob.active_material = mat

    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob)
```